# javascript generated table I need to assign a seperate id to each generated cell.

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a table generated by JavaScript that inserts a row/cell in a loop. Each loop has data pull from a php file. I am trying to assign a unique id to each cell after I have made the cells clickable. I can click on the cell to get the id but cell one states id of 1, then cell 2 states id of 2 but when I click on cell one again it has the id of 2 not the id of one it previously had. I have included my code below. If anyone can see my mistake or just point me in the right direction, please, let me know.

```
<table id="myTable">
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br>

<p onload="myFunction()"></p>
<script>  <!-- below is the function for the new items.-->
    var i = 0;
    function myFunction() {
            setInterval(function() {
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            var row = table.insertRow(0);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            cell1.id = "i";
            cell1.onclick = function(){alert(i);};
            cell1.innerHTML = "<?php include('Trick.php')?>";
            i++;
            },10000);} 
</script>
```

below is my css file:

```
 table, th, td {

        border-collapse: seperate;
        border-spacing: 10px 10px;
        width: 100%;
        border:visible='false';
        color:white;
        font-size:34px;
        z-index:9;

        }
            td:hover {
            background-color:limegreen;
            }
    td{background-color:gray};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are assigning the letter "i" as id:

> **cell1.id = "i";**

And second, when you make alert, the alert box shows the value of the **global** variable i, which value will be the same for all elements ( the last value )

```
var i = 0;
function myFunction() {
    setInterval(function() {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.id = i;

        cell1.addEventListener("click",function(){
            alert(this.id);
        });

        cell1.innerHTML = "aaaaa";
        i++;
    },1000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed my problem. I did not even catch that mistake.